# Two buttons overlap when positioning them? (HTML/CSS)

Tags: html, css, button, input, responsive

I created two buttons that I would like to place under my input login boxes. I want it to be responsive so I used the absolute value but when I move them, the buttons suddenly overlap! Any solutions? Here is my index and stylesheet:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
header {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)), url(hero.jpeg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  height: 100vh;
}
.login {
  position: absolute;
  /* Turns the the text box to absolute from static (allows free control of placement) */
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 420px;
  top: 30%;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  height: auto;
  font-size: 20pt;
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding: 15px;
}
#space-password {
  padding-top: 20px;
}
html {
  color: whitesmoke;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-family: 'Lato', 'Arial', sans-serif;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)), url(hero.jpeg);
}
input {
  border-radius: 50px;
  height: 38px;
  width: 100%;
  color: aliceblue;
  border: 2px solid #999;
  background-color: #34495e;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-left: 14px;
  padding-right: 14px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: 'Lato', 'Arial', sans-serif;
}
.btn:link,
.btn:visited {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  /*This padding and border radius round border and define how big it is */
  font-weight: 300;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 200px;
  transition: background-color 0.2s, border 0.2s, color 0.2s;
  /* makes color subtly change instead of instantly. More applealing */
}
.btn-full:link,
.btn-full:visited {
  background-color: #3498db;
  /* From flat UI colors */
  border: 1px solid #3498db;
  color: #fff;
}
.btn-ghost:link,
.btn-ghost:visited {
  border: 1px solid #3498db;
  color: #3498db;
}
.btn:hover,
.btn:active {
  background-color: #7cbde8;
}
.btn-full:hover,
.btn-full:active {
  border: 1px solid #3498db;
  /* Fixed issue of text disipearing in color and borders being different color for both full and ghost */
}
.btn-ghost:hover,
.btn-ghost:active {
  border: 1px solid #3498db;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html lan="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendors/css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Welcome-Sign in</title>

</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <form class="login">
      <p>Apple ID:</p>
      <br>
      <input type="text" name="Apple ID">
      <br>
      <p id="space-password">Password:</p>
      <br>
      <input type="password" name="Password">
    </form>
    <div>
      <a class="btn btn-full" href="#">Login</a>
      <a class="btn btn-ghost" href="#">Don't have an acount? Sign up!</a>
    </div>

  </header>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Why do you think that you should use absolute positionin to make it responsive? It would be really hard to make page responsive with absolute positioned items. Familiarize yourself with css media queries instead: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

There is no relation between `position:absolute` and responsive design.
Since you intend to do this with absolute, Just place your button div into the form.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
header {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)), url(hero.jpeg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  height: 100vh;
}
.login {
  position: absolute;
  /* Turns the the text box to absolute from static (allows free control of placement) */
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 420px;
  top: 30%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0px;
  height: auto;
  font-size: 20pt;
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding: 15px;
}
#space-password {
  padding-top: 20px;
}
html {
  color: whitesmoke;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-family: 'Lato', 'Arial', sans-serif;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)), url(hero.jpeg);
}
input {
  border-radius: 50px;
  height: 38px;
  width: 100%;
  color: aliceblue;
  border: 2px solid #999;
  background-color: #34495e;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-left: 14px;
  padding-right: 14px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: 'Lato', 'Arial', sans-serif;
}
.btn{
  margin-top:30px;
  font-size: 14px !important;
}
.btn:link,
.btn:visited {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  /*This padding and border radius round border and define how big it is */
  font-weight: 300;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 200px;
  transition: background-color 0.2s, border 0.2s, color 0.2s;
  /* makes color subtly change instead of instantly. More applealing */
}
.btn-full:link,
.btn-full:visited {
  background-color: #3498db;
  /* From flat UI colors */
  border: 1px solid #3498db;
  color: #fff;
}
.btn-ghost:link,
.btn-ghost:visited {
  border: 1px solid #3498db;
  color: #3498db;
}
.btn:hover,
.btn:active {
  background-color: #7cbde8;
}
.btn-full:hover,
.btn-full:active {
  border: 1px solid #3498db;
  /* Fixed issue of text disipearing in color and borders being different color for both full and ghost */
}
.btn-ghost:hover,
.btn-ghost:active {
  border: 1px solid #3498db;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html lan="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendors/css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Welcome-Sign in</title>

</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <form class="login">
      <p>Apple ID:</p>
      <br>
      <input type="text" name="Apple ID">
      <br>
      <p id="space-password">Password:</p>
      <br>
      <input type="password" name="Password">
       <div>
      <a class="btn btn-full" href="#">Login</a>
      <a class="btn btn-ghost" href="#">Don't have an acount? Sign up!</a>
    </div>
    </form>
   

  </header>

</body>

</html>
```

**Edit:** This is for your comment. Also i recommend you to make use of Media queries for responsive layout.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
header {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)), url(hero.jpeg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  height: 100vh;
}
.login {
  position: absolute;
  /* Turns the the text box to absolute from static (allows free control of placement) */
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 420px;
  top: 30%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0px;
  height: auto;
  font-size: 20pt;
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding: 15px;
}
#space-password {
  padding-top: 20px;
}
html {
  color: whitesmoke;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-family: 'Lato', 'Arial', sans-serif;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)), url(hero.jpeg);
}
input {
  border-radius: 50px;
  height: 38px;
  width: 100%;
  color: aliceblue;
  border: 2px solid #999;
  background-color: #34495e;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-left: 14px;
  padding-right: 14px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: 'Lato', 'Arial', sans-serif;
}
.btn {
  margin-top: 30px;
  font-size: 14px !important;
}
.btn:link,
.btn:visited {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  /*This padding and border radius round border and define how big it is */
  font-weight: 300;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 200px;
  transition: background-color 0.2s, border 0.2s, color 0.2s;
  /* makes color subtly change instead of instantly. More applealing */
}
.btn-full:link,
.btn-full:visited {
  background-color: #3498db;
  /* From flat UI colors */
  border: 1px solid #3498db;
  color: #fff;
}
.btn-ghost:link,
.btn-ghost:visited {
  border: 1px solid #3498db;
  color: #3498db;
}
.btn:hover,
.btn:active {
  background-color: #7cbde8;
}
.btn-full:hover,
.btn-full:active {
  border: 1px solid #3498db;
  /* Fixed issue of text disipearing in color and borders being different color for both full and ghost */
}
.btn-ghost:hover,
.btn-ghost:active {
  border: 1px solid #3498db;
  color: #fff;
}
.btns {
   position: absolute;
      /* Turns the the text box to absolute from static (allows free control of placement) */
      width: 100%;
      top: 300px;
      left: 15%;
      right: 0px;
      height: auto;
      font-size: 14pt;
      margin: 0px auto;
      padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html lan="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendors/css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Welcome-Sign in</title>

</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <form class="login">
      <p>Apple ID:</p>
      <br>
      <input type="text" name="Apple ID">
      <br>
      <p id="space-password">Password:</p>
      <br>
      <input type="password" name="Password">

    </form>
    <div class="btns">
      <a class="btn btn-full" href="#">Login</a>
      <a class="btn btn-ghost" href="#">Don't have an acount? Sign up!</a>
    </div>

  </header>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This didn't help one bit, but thank you for your input. Like I said, when I do that the buttons overlap. Wanted a way to place both buttons how I want to.

Comment: @TempleNaylor check it now

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `<a></a>` tag to create buttons you can use `<button></button>` tag to create button. This will avoid the overlapping of buttons.

```
    <!DOCTYPE>
    <html lan="en">
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendors/css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Welcome-Sign in</title>

</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <form class="login">
            <p>Apple ID:</p><br>
            <input type="text" name="Apple ID"><br>
            <p id="space-password">Password:</p><br>
            <input type="password" name="Password">
        </form>
        <div>
            <button class="btn btn-full" >Login</button>
            <button class="btn btn-ghost">Don't have an acount? Sign up!      </button>
        </div>

    </header>

 </body>
```

Comment: Don't see how this helps in any way? That is just my index code that is still the same.